# How to get a Contextual Action Bar visibility?

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

My question is pretty simple.
How can I get a `Contextual Action Bar` (CAB) visibility?

For instance, I have a `ActionMode` and a callback.

```
mActionMode = activity.startActionMode(mCallback);
```

Now I need to know if the CAB is visible or not. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess there is no built-in solution for this problem.

I have solved it by setting a `boolean` flag in my callback class

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
{
    this.visible = true;
    /**/
    return true;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
{       
    this.visible = false;
    /**/
}
```

Then, it is possible to use `callback.isVisible();`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of querying that. But the answer suggested by @RafaelC is unnecessary(sorry mate no hard feelings)... your code is already designed so u can know when is visible. See when u start the action mode, a reference to the ActionMode object is saved in your member variable:

```
mActionMode = activity.startActionMode(mCallback);
```

Then in your onDestroyActionMode, if you dont have it yet add this line:

```
mActioinMode=null;
```

That's it!

Now:

```
if(mActionMode!=null) //your ActionMode bar is visible

if(mActionMode==null) //your ActinMode bar is not visible.
```

Hope this helps new coders... Regards :)

Comment: Hi Osagui, thanks for chipping in. This question is from 3 years ago, and I haven't done any more Android since then. Don't remember a thing haha :} Will keep both answers as alternative for future ppl coming from google !